# Can't get the value from ajax response div

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

When my ajax response is successful, i have the following code:

```
success : function(response) {
               $('#texto').append(response);
          }
```

this is the response html I append:

```
<body>
{% load custom_filters %}
{% for modulo in modulos %}
<div align="left" class="result" value="{{ modulo.nome }}">
    {{ modulo.nome }} {{ modulo.versao }}.{{ modulo.chave_revisao|soma_um|mascara_versao }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The divs appears, but when I'm going to use their values I'm getting an empty string. And the comparation goes false.

```
$('.result').each(function(){
                    for (i=0; i<=vetBuscar.length;i++){
                        if($(this).val() == vetBuscar[i]){
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            vetBuscar.pop(i)
                        }
                    }
```

Anyone knows how can i get this value?

Comment: Why does your response contains `<body>` tag?

Comment: Are you adding Django template tags/for loops to the div after the AJAX call is done? Those are evaluated when rendering the template BEFORE sending it to the client. If you add them after a successful AJAX call they will not be evaluated which means that there will only be one div with the class="result" and it will have the value="{{ modulo.name }}" not whatever that variable will hold.

Comment: @goliney it's just a typo, thanks

Comment: @Mikael I don't think so.
The thing I'm doing here is:
- I make the ajax call;
- The view processes and returns me this minor template (it's a separate one);
- Then, when the request is successful, I add the html to my main template.

My problem is that I can't get this div's value.
If there is a problem in my way of requesting the data, warn me please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

instead of:

```
$(this).val()
```

Normally divs don't have a `value` attribute, and the `.val()` method is intended for (form) elements that do.

Or you may like to use an html5 `data-` attribute and use:

```
<div align="left" class="result" data-value="{{ modulo.nome }}">
```

And then:

```
$(this).attr("data-value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that when your page loads, the elements you're looking for haven't been loaded yet so your selector isn't bound to anything yet. This is actually a common problem when loading html using javascript.

Check out the jQuery .on() event handler, I think it could be exactly what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/on/